# How do you write binary protocol parser

Tags: c#, parsing, binary, protocols

This is how I read the input stream

```
while (!stopRequested && stream.CanRead)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];

    Int32 bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
    byte[] response = new byte[bytesRead];
    Array.Copy(buffer, response, bytesRead);

    responsesStream.AddRange(response); //push the bytes onto the dataStream
    ParseStream(responsesStream); //attempt to parse
}
```

How do you implement an efficient binary protocol parser given that you have a spec like in following example [image]

Concise code samples or links highly appreciated. thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary communications protocol parser design for serial data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278227/binary-communications-protocol-parser-design-for-serial-data)

Comment: Is it just 10 bytes that need to be read? Why not just read 10 bytes from the buffer into a byte array of 10? Asking how to 'efficiently' read just 10 bytes is a bit overkill. We're talking about microseconds here

Comment: @mybirthname the message size is variable based on second byte